# Downloading zip file using curl (c++)

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to download a zip file using curl from a localhost server

```
http://localhost:8080/zip/json.zip?assetIds=<comma-separated asset ids>
```

when I type the url on my browser the file starts downloading with no problem.
So when I tried to use curl to an already existing zip file :

```
RestClient::response RestClient::get(const std::string& url)
{
  RestClient::response ret = {};


  CURL *curl = NULL;
  CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
  FILE *fp
  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if (curl)
  {
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
       char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/Users/stage/Documents/temp/json.zip";
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "./ca-bundle.crt");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, RestClient::write_data);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);


        int i=fclose(fp);
        if( i==0)
            system("unzip -j json.zip");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, RestClient::write_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ret);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, RestClient::header_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA, &ret);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
      ret.body = "Failed to query.";
      ret.code = -1;
      return ret;
    }
    long http_code = 0;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    ret.code = static_cast<int>(http_code);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
  }

  return ret;
}
```

and the function for writing to the file

```
size_t RestClient::write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}
```

when I run the code I get a message :

```
Archive:  json.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of json.zip or
    json.zip.zip, and cannot find json.zip.ZIP, period.
```

The json.zip file that used to contain an image becomes an EMPTY file not even a zip :/
Does somebody know what went wrong?

Comment: _"when I type the url on my browser the file starts downloading with no problem"_ Explore this more. What really happens? Are there any redirects? What are the HTTP request and response headers? Perhaps you need to do more work in your C++ implementation to better mimic the HTTP transaction taking place inside your browser for this resource.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue with the curl command in my script (not C++). I finally looked at the .zip file that was downloaded in a text editor and found it contained an HTML error message instead of being the actual file I thought I downloaded. I then did some debugging in my script and copied the URL I was creating and pasted it into my browser. I got the same error message when I checked the URL.

Long story short, I had a typo in my URL. I would venture to guess that you're having a very similar issue.

In my case however, it was as easy as calling the shell command "curl -o", your C++ code seems a bit more complicated than what I was doing.

I hope this helps in same way.